# LibreOffice Writer fonts

Tags: libreoffice

I downloaded the KDP template (https://kdp.amazon.com/en_US/help/topic/A16ABVH839JCP0?ref_=kdp_ts_pb_man) but all the Styles are different fonts.

How can I get them all to be the same font?

Everytime I press Enter I seem to get a new font!

Comment: LibreOffice is cross-platform, not limited to Unix & Linux. Your question would be more appropriate for [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: I looked into these templates, and they seem to use Garamond for basically any style element you should be using, at least in the `Paperback_Manuscript_Template.zip`'s English templates. So it's not clear where you're seeing different fonts.